# How to create a browse button to select a folder in php or any supporting languages?

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

How can i select a folder in browse button. I mean, i want to upload a folder or file. So is it possible?

Comment: just tried html tag input with file type

Comment: You can't upload a "folder", but you can create it with PHP, you also can upload files. But you have to do some efforts :)

Comment: You can't upload a folder. But the input file will allow you to upload one file at a time.

Comment: so can is it possible with javascript? or jquery or any php supporting languages

Comment: you can upload mutiple files by the help of html5.there is no specific way define for upload floder.but if you upload folders all  files this can be down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just tried html tag input with file type

That's all about HTML and has nothing to do with PHP (at least until the data is submitted).

HTML provides no mechanism to select folders for upload.

HTML 5 allows [multiple](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple) files to be selected. I assume this would be handled in PHP the same way as any other kind of multiple value response would be handled - make sure the name ends in `[]` then treat it as an array in `$_POST`.

Comment: so can is it possible with java script? or jquery or any php supporting languages

Comment: Browser based JavaScript provides no mechanism to access files other than through HTML's File Input control . jQuery isn't a language, it is a bunch of pretty JavaScript, everything that can be said about JS can be said about jQuery. Browser plugins (Java, Flash, ActiveX) *might* be able to do stuff with directories and send results over HTTP, but you would have to define how the directories would be handled as there is no standard way to transmit one over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is only possible in chrome (and possibly only in a nightly build).

I could be wrong but googling things is just too much effort

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input name="myfile" type="file" />` in a form and `$_FILES` in PHP to get the uploaded file.

I think Chrome 11+ also supports uploading folders, but there is no HTML-Only Solution that works for all browsers.

Edit: [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) supports uploading multiple files. Maybe that is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response i know about this, my thinking is upload entire folder.